# Двоеточие перед однородными определениями возможно?

Tags: пунктуация

На сайте  "Грамма":

Вопрос 5917:    В правилах написано, что перед приложением, идущим в конце предложения, нужно ставить тире, а как быть с обычным определением? С несколькими однородными определениями? Там допустима только запятая или, может быть, двоеточие нужно? Например, вот в такой фразе:"Она снова услышала кашель (?) сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже лающий".

Ответ:   Начнем с того, что приложение – разновидность определения. Таким образом, то, что справедливо для приложения, – справедливо для любого другого обособленного определения. В предложениях о кашле и запахе можно поставить запятую
Она снова услышала кашель, сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже лающий".
 – типичный для обособленного определения знак; 
можно поставить тире, которое не только станет сигналом обособления, но и подчеркнет его особую смысловую роль в предложении. 
Она снова услышала кашель – сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже лающий".
В первом предложении допустимо и двоеточие, если автор намерен обратить внимание на список определений, его поясняющее назначение.
Она снова услышала кашель: сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже лающий.

Конец цитаты.

Но у Розенталя нет ни одного примера в разделе об обособленных определениях, чтобы было двоеточие перед определениями. И в разделе о вариативных знаках "Двоеточие - тире" тоже нет.

Может, двоеточие объяснимо этим:

3. Если однородным членам предложения не предшествует обобщающее слово (словосочетание), то перед ними двоеточие ставится только в том случае, когда необходимо предупредить читателя, что дальше следует перечисление: Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и ещё какие-то привлекательные узелки и коробочки (Л. Т.); Тут были: Павел, чухонец, штабс-капитан Ярошевич, фельдфебель Максименко, красная фуражка, дама с белыми зубами, доктор (Ч.). Ср. в деловой и научной речи: На заседании присутствовали:…; Для получения смеси нужно взять:…; Роли исполняют:…; В ролях: …

Ведь "сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже лающий" -- это однородные члены.

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 2):

Она снова услышала кашель – сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже лающий.

1) Однородный ряд определений в конце предложения **обычно обособляется тире**, например: Посёлок лежит вдоль леса – пыльный, сухой  прямой. Мы долго шли по обочине дороги – бурой, ещё не высохшей от снега, сплошь покрытой прошлогодними листьями.

2) **Можно ли поставить запятую?** Можно, но хорошо получается, если два определения связаны союзом И, то есть составляют единую фразу: Она снова услышала кашель, сухой и отрывистый.

3) **А двоеточие?** Практически знак редко применяется, но не стоит считать его невозможным или запрещенным: Она снова услышала кашель: сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже лающий.

Двоеточие предупреждает  о последующем перечислении, в устной речи делается увеличенная пауза. Автор таким образом предлагает нам  обратить **особое внимание** именно на однородный ряд определений. В случае тире этот ряд идет как присоединительный.

4) Аналогия с обобщающими словами вполне уместна, например:

Коты **всех мастей** – рыжие, чёрные, седые и белые с подпалинами – берут дом в осаду. Весь пейзаж был написан всего **несколькими** красками – голубой, белой и лиловой с несколькими оттенками.

В нашем случае обобщающее слово отсутствует, читатель должен сам его представить, например: "особенный, вызывающий тревогу".

Answer (score 1):

Ответ Граммы.ру.

Современные правила пунктуации допускают в таких случаях постановку тире, но не двоеточия: "Она снова услышала кашель - сухой, отрывистый и какой-то даже 
лающий". См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М.. 2009. С. 206-207; Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по пункуации. М., 1984. С. 47.